# Angular - How do I delete local files? (unrelated to records)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a delete photo method in my angular application. This works, even displays a nice toaster animation and refreshes the list.
It deletes the records in my database, but seperate to the database I have an assets/images folder in my src/app.
I was wondering how would I go about deleting this file? The file has exactly the same name as the id, and also they're all .jpegs.
I was wondering If i could do something like:

```
deleteFile(id){
   delete("../src/app/assets/images/' + id + '.jpeg'")
}.
```

I'm just unaware of how exactly this is done.
Any suggestions?
On small applications it isn't an issue, so for this project it's fine if I don't get it, but I want to learn how to do it for scalability.
Thanks! Mark

Comment: This sounds like a job for the backend; not Angular. If you setup a REST API, you could implement a DELETE endpoint, and that handles deleting from both the database and assets. The specifics would depend on your backend though.

Comment: You basically want to do the reverse of originally adding the image to file system and as a reference in the database.  Look to where ever you do that for inspiration on how to do the opposite.

Comment: Images on your Angular app are in memory, frontend wise, just stop referencing it (e.g splice it from an array) the actual removal from memory will happen when user closes the application. Garbage collection is performed automatically. We cannot force or prevent it. Once user downloaded the image to their filesystem it's out of your reach anyway. I highly doubt that what you want to do is to delete files on user computer or in the server. Re-think this, store images (the blob) in a data structure where you can easily add/remove/toggle items (e.g Array or Map).

Comment: Thanks! I'll go onto my api here and see about reverse engineering it.
Thank you for the help, I believe I was getting caught up on doing it with the frontend